# return unique element of array of object using filter()

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I'm not able to produce unique array, not sure what's wrong with below logic using filter().

https://jsbin.com/mufobevezo/edit?js,console,output

```
 var uniqueProducts = json.filter(function(elem, i, array) {
            return array.indexOf(elem) === i;
        }
    );

    console.log(uniqueProducts);
```

The code I took from here https://danmartensen.svbtle.com/javascripts-map-reduce-and-filter. Not sure what the indexOf do in the example.

I just want to know if the link above has some mistake.

Comment: the second and third entries in the array may have the same values, but they are still different objects

Comment: How do you determine uniqueness when the elements in your array are objects? Probably by `id`, but you'll have to use it explicitly. Mere `indexOf` would not suffice.

Comment: @Rhumborl so any idea why indexOf come into the picture? Did he made a mistake?

Comment: Please show us how you are calling that function where it does not produce the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to know if the link above has some mistake.
>   Not sure what the indexOf do in the example.

OK.Let's look at the code:

```
 var uniqueProducts = json.filter(function(elem, i, array) {
            return array.indexOf(elem) === i;
        }
    );

    console.log(uniqueProducts);
```

Say you have this array : `[5,2,3,5]`

The `filter` function will run 4 times.

`[5,2,3,5].indexOf(5) === 0;` //true , filter will return true
`[5,2,3,5].indexOf(2) === 1;` //true , filter will return true
`[5,2,3,5].indexOf(3) === 2;` //true , filter will return true
`[5,2,3,5].indexOf(5) === 3;` //false (!). Index of (5) is **the first index** which is 0  , not 3 , hence function return false. so look what just happened  , a previous found element was not added to the collection ( and so dup is removed).

So all you'll have is  5,2,3 , which is the unique numbers of the array.

better?

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach will work for you.

```
 Array.prototype.unique = function() {
    var tmp = {},
      out = [];
    for (var i = 0, n = this.length; i < n; ++i) {
      if (!tmp[this[i]]) {
        tmp[this[i]] = true;
        out.push(this[i]);
      }
    }
    return out;
  }
```

Comment: Is this your own code? Care to explain the *approach*?

Comment: I could have use loadash and use _.uniq but my question is why the author used indexOf with filter.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a small hash and check against it.

https://jsbin.com/pujuvadaxi/edit?js,console,output

```
var json = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  }
]
var tmp ={};
var uniqueProducts = json.filter(function(elem) {
        var exists = tmp[JSON.stringify(elem)];
        if (!exists) {
          tmp[JSON.stringify(elem)]=true;
        }
        return !exists; 
    } 
);

console.log(uniqueProducts);
```

Comment: Why stringify ?

Comment: It creates a string key from the object that can be easily compared against another serialized duplicate object.